# Using clipboard.js in a Bootsrap modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, clipboard.js

I encounter a problem with Chrome, FF and IE 11... When in a bootstrap modal clipboard.js doesn't copy the string in the clipboard. I did a test using the same code to copy from the main page and from a modal. This is working fine within the main page but not within the modal.

I have add a listener on clipboard success with basic information and I obtain exactly the same information on the console with both... So from its point off view the string it successfully copied even within the modal??

```
clipboard = new Clipboard('a[href^=\\\\], a[href^=file]');
clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
    console.info('Action:', e.action);
    console.info('Text:', e.text);
    console.info('Trigger:', e.trigger);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SamuelC/uhc51of1/15/

Comment: Please see https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/issues/155

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Ben Jackson's answer I have solved my problem.
Just by adding:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function() {};
```

So far this bootstrap modal modification doesn't affect any other JS library I am using within modals...